# How to configure Linux (debian 11) as an SMTP Gateway with authentication

Tags: debian, email, smtp

Hope you are all having a good friday.

The situation is - I have a local MS Exchange Server, which currently has a windows based server in the cloud that I'm using as an SMTP relay - it works great and has for years. However, I no longer need the advanced options and so the cost of hosting it solely for use as an SMTP relay is no longer viable.

I can get a linux server hosted for less than a cup of coffee per month. I'm a newbie to linux. I've scoured the net for how to setup linux to act as an smtp relay for the last 4 days straight. All the tutorials are based on how to configure linux server to use an smtp relay with third party.

I would really appreciate some assistance. I simply want to have linux behave as a working smtp relay for my exchange server. I have multiple domain names, so the relay would need to work with them.

Thanks in advance.

I haven't tried anything yet. As I haven't found reliable information for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You can do this with either Exim or Postfix. I use Exim. Don't use OVH as your hosting provider unless you're already using them and have a clean IP address. (They are really good for many things but sending email isn't one of them.) Do ensure your provider will let you send SMTP